# How to store input values in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

How would I store the values that I have taken as an input from the user from both of these inputs to display together as an upcoming "event" and be able to do this multiple different times for different events?

```html
<label for="eventlocation">Event Location (1 to 20 characters):</label>

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="20" size="20">

<label for="datetime">Event Date and Time:</label>

<input type="datetime-local" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="20" size="20">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save and read data like this

```js
const nameTxt = document.querySelector('#name');
const date = document.querySelector('#date');


nameTxt.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem('name', event.target.value);
});

date.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem('date', event.target.value);
});

function getSavedData() {
  console.log('name', localStorage.getItem('name'));
  console.log('date', localStorage.getItem('date'));

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <label for="eventlocation">Event Location (1 to 20 characters):</label>

  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="1" maxlength="20"
    size="20">

  <label for="datetime">Event Date and Time:</label>

  <input type="datetime-local" id="date" name="date" required minlength="1"
    maxlength="20" size="20">


  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```